# Buttons don't work after scrolling on mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a `phonegap` application using `jQuery Mobile` running on `android.` For some reason buttons cease to function when I scroll down. In other words, the page must be scrolled all the way to the top for any button to work. I even tried listening for `jQuery tap` and `click` events but those don't fire either. I am scratching my head at this one!

Comment: did you see any error in console?

Comment: nope, no error thrown